# How did Megatron learn English?

Tags: plot-explanation, transformers, transformers-2007

In *Transformers*, when Megatron was able to break free, he says "I am Megatron.".

But how was he able to do it, given that the Transformers had to learn English from the world wide web and Megatron has been asleep/frozen for thousands of years.

For evidence, Optimus Prime tells Sam Witwicky that they learned English from world wide web.

Comment: they used internet

Comment: Not really an answer, but a note that AI can learn things way way *way* faster than humans can.  Given that Megatron is a super-advanced alien robot AI (not to mention a *true sentient AI*), he may well be able to learn even faster than the rudimentary AIs we have today.  So, maybe the few seconds between his mind "booting up" and his robot body "breaking free" were enough for him to detect wireless internet signals and "learn English" the same way the Autobots did.

Comment: BTW, this is how I wake up every morning. My eyes open and I yell "I ... am ... BRETT!!"

Comment: @Steve-O Seems like an acceptable argument.

Comment: Megatron was on earth much longer than the autobots, he could have learned something along the way. The Autobots had to learn much faster due to their recent arrival.

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths Then Megatron might have not learnt modern English, isn't it?

Comment: @naive Sure, why not, but in a movie series full of plot holes anything is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember how the original primes communicated with Sam in english, although they were dead a LONG time ago (and even the fallen-one and the ancient decepticon-turned-autobot) who all predate WWW etc.
All I want to say is that it was Transformers1, the intro to these series, I would like to highlight that it contains a couple or more plot-holes(if that is the correct word for it).

I guess that all is forgiven in the first movie as they needed English to convey the foundation of the story to audience.
Luckily to add to the logical part for the viewers, there's this scene with Prime stating "we used the WorldWideWeb ".

Also,they are advanced beings,not only they pre-date us, but are WAY MORE technologically advanced (a shitty decepticon cracked into NASA and what not).
Some of us viewers(myself included) believe Starscream or any other higher decepticon must have been continuously been communicating with him.
Many others say that it's left for us viewers to guess.

Answer (score -3):

I am aware of nothing in the movies that explains this.  Perhaps Megatron was in "standby" mode and still able to receive/record outside signals.  When we finally came back "online" his database updated and he "knew" the English language.

Comment: lol its just a theory..:)

Comment: this would help you, [here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)